# Webmin CentOS7 AWS backup errors - perl(S3::AWSAuthConnection) can't be installed

Tags: perl, amazon-s3, webmin

A few days ago Webmin S3 site backups began to fail. Error notice was as follows:

> Can't locate Time/Piece.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /vendor_perl /usr/libexec/webmin /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 . .. .. /usr/libexec/webmin/virtual-server) at Net/Amazon/Signature/V4.pm line 8.
> BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Net/Amazon/Signature/V4.pm line 8.
> Compilation failed in require at S3/AWSAuthConnection.pm line 28.
> BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at S3/AWSAuthConnection.pm line 28.
> Compilation failed in require at (eval 399) line 2.
> BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at (eval 399) line 2.

I went to the backup config and the S3 Accounts complained that perl(S3::AWSAuthConnection) was not installed, but it was unavailable when trying to install from command line or the Perl Modules interface.

> Installing package(s) with command /bin/yum -y install perl(S3::AWSAuthConnection) ..

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.steadfastnet.com
 * centos-sclo-rh: mnvoip.mm.fcix.net
 * centos-sclo-sclo: mnvoip.mm.fcix.net
 * epel: epel.stl.us.ssimn.org
 * extras: nyc.mirrors.clouvider.net
 * remi-php74: mirror.usi.edu
 * remi-safe: mirror.usi.edu
 * rpmfusion-free-updates: muug.ca
 * updates: linux-mirrors.fnal.gov
No package perl(S3::AWSAuthConnection) available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that installing Net::Amazon::S3 worked for me. I don't know why it started failing, but installing this one will correct communications with S3.

```
https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Amazon::S3

Module name
Net::Amazon::S3 0.89-2.el7
Description
Use the Amazon S3 - Simple Storage Service
Installed on
Mon Jun 22 03:44:17 2020
Module file
/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Net/Amazon/S3.pm
Installed from
RPM package perl-Net-Amazon-S3
```